# unable to cast object to type query of type ienumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my grid one DataField is loaded from code and not from the db. I thought that I could do something like this to make this happen.

Is it possible to really do this like this

**Grid class**

```
protected void rgGrid_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int item = 0; item<=this.rgGrid.Items.Count-1; item++)
    {
        GridDataItem dataItem = this.rgGrid.Items[item];

        double  NumberOfDays = ((IEnumerable<MonthReportRowItem>)this.rgGrid.DataSource).ElementAt(item).NumberOfDays;
    }
}
```

**MonthRep (where the data field is "generated")**

```
public double  NumberOfDays
{
    get
    {
        return (this.VacationDays - this.BookedVacationDays) + this.UsedVacationDays;
    }
}
```

cause I receive a error message

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Should I try a different approach or i this just a minor bug ?

Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: Isn't it possible to use the `DataItem` property of the `GridDataItem` to get the element directly? As in `((MonthReportRowItem)dataItem.DataItem).NumberOfDays`

Comment: @Me.Name Thanks for your comment but : Unable to cast object of type 'HolidayTracker.Data.Model.HtVacationDay' to type 'HolidayTracker.Report.MonthReportRowItem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double  NumberOfDays =
        this.rgGrid.DataSource
                .Cast<MonthReportRowItem>()
                .ElementAt(item)
                .NumberOfDays;
```

Perhaps your `DataSource` is of type `ObjectQuery` not of type `ObjectQuery<T>` so you can cast it to `IEnumerable<MonthReportRowItem>` using `Cast<T>()`, get the element at the desired position, then get property.

Comment: It is extension method from the Linq. Have you `using System.Linq` in your code?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, so the docs seem to suggest that you should swap out `AsEunumerable` with `AsQueryable`

Comment: @Niko.K, you haven't figured out the issue? Can you show the exact exception do you have?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan heey nope I tried every solution that you guys provide me and it still doesn't work .For your solution I receive 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Cast<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the `DataSource` property is an object, so you need to cast it to the `ObjectQuery` before calling `AsEnumerable`. So this should do the job:

```
((ObjectQuery)this.rgGrid.DataSource).AsEnumerable()
            .Cast<MonthReportRowItem>()
            .ElementAt(item)
            .NumberOfDays
```

Where `AsEunumerable` is in the `System.Linq` namespace.

Comment: do I have to add some special using ?

Comment: I think you need to add `System.Linq`, but that should be enough.